# NoMethodError in HealthReport#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep get this error when I want to render my form

The error is pointing the     <%= form_for(@hreport) do |f| %>, I'm not sure where when wrong or i missed something, anyone help is appreciate!

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <%= form_for(@hreports) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :"Student ID" %>
        <%= f.text_field :studentid, class: 'form-control' %>
```

This is my health_report_controller.rb

```
class HealthReportController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @hreports = Healthreport.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
  end

  def new
    @hreports = Healthreport.new
  end

  def create
    @hreports = current_user.healthreports.build(hreport_params)
    if @hreports.save
      flash[:success] = "Report Submitted!"
    else

    end

  end


  def show
    @hreports = Healthreport.find(params[:id])
  end


  private

  def set_hreport
    @hreport = Healthreport.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def hreport_params
    params.require(:Healthreport).permit(:date, :studentid, :department, :issue)
  end
end
```

This is my view

```
<% provide(:title, 'New Report') %>
<h1>Health and Safety Report</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <%= form_for(@hreports) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :"Student ID" %>
        <%= f.text_field :studentid, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :"Department of applicant" %>
        <%= f.text_field :department, class: 'form-control' %>

        <%= f.label :"Description of Issues" %>
        <%= f.text_area :issue, placeholder: "Write your report here...",  class: 'form-control' %>


        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

This is my healthreport.rb inside model folder

```
class Healthreport < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is my healthreport.rb inside db folder

```
class CreateHealthreports < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :healthreports do |t|
      t.datetime :date
      t.string :studentid
      t.string :department
      t.string :issue

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

It's migration db file

```
class AddUserToHealthreport < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :healthreports, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the health report model file?  I believe you have a simple naming error.

Comment: Yep I have edited my question, is that the one you want?

Comment: Are you sure this is how you model is declared? There seems to be some spelling mistakes, or something off. For example the model healthreport.rb should be class Healthreport < ActiveRecord::Base
however you have it written differently

Comment: There's 2 healthreport.rb, the one i posted first in inside the model folder. The updated is the one inside db folder

Comment: And the error message is `NoMethodError in HealthReport#new` or `NoMethodError in Healthreport#new` ??  (camelcase capital R)

Comment: The error is NoMethodError in HealthReport#new

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you do this:

```
def new
  @hreports = Healthreport.new
end
```

But in the view, you are expecting this

```
<%= form_for(@hreport) do |f| %>
```

You are passing `@hreports` but trying to use `@hreport`.  Change the controller to be

```
def new
  @hreport = Healthreport.new
end
```

(the index action should use the plural, the other actions should use the singular)

Two Rails convention/style things you should be aware of:

1. A singular variable name (such as @hreport) refers to a single object; a plural of that name (@hreports) refers to an array or an ActiveRecord relationship.
2. Model and Controller should use the same naming style: if the controller is named `health_report_controller.rb` and defines a `HealthReportController`, then the model file should be named `health_report.rb` and should define a `HealthReport` class.

Comment: updated view given by the OP is using the correct variable, find it in the end of the question.

Comment: uh, ok, then I'm stumped.  @Gary Vlc can you please verify that the controller & model are exactly as you've written (in the last edit) with regards to capitalization and pluralization?  If you define a class `HealthReport`, then the call `Healthreport.new` is going to throw that error, since Rails has no idea what the `Healthreport` class is.

Comment: I assume the class you saying is the controller right? My actual controller name is health_report_controller.rb but I'm using RubyMine as IDE it automatically change it to HealthReport, will it affect anything?

Comment: The error "NoMethodError in HealthReport#new" means that there is an error in the new action of the HealthReport controller.  That error is, obviously, on the only line of the code - `@hreports = Healthreport.new`.  There is no .new method defined for the Healthreport class, which is what leads me to ask whether your model file (app/models/...) is written correctly.  I think you have a naming & consistency error between the model & the controller.

Comment: Then what you propose me to do in order to fix this problem?

Comment: Open the console.  Type `hr1 = Healthreport.new` and `hr2 = HealthReport.new`.  Do either of those work?

Comment: OK.  So far so good.  Then put a breakpoint at the very beginning of the create controller, and see what `hreport_params` is.  Given that your form is for `@hreports`, I suspect that `hreport_params` will be non-existent, but `hreports_params` will have the data you want.